# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Snippets

Tags: sql-server-2008, code-snippets, ssms

Is there a snippets feature in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. But you can use templates instead. With them you can achieve similar results.

Comment: And here is a blog post about templates, how to create and use them http://ctrlshiftb.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/snippets-for-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/

Answer (score 7):

[SSMS Tools Pack - add-in for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com) - has this feature.

Comment: For SQL 2008, this is the best option. Thanks